# How to set the cell.imageview frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have table view in which 
I want my Image view to reset the frame

I used the following code:

```
[[cell imageView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,32,32)];
```

But nothing is working

Please let me know how to resize the default imageView section

Thanks

Comment: This is your 8th question on stackoverflow, yet none of your questions have an accepted answer. You should change that and accept the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 17):

The best way is to add `- (void)layoutSubviews` to your cell subclass like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCell` have a fixed layout, depending on the style you use when you initialize it. You cannot change that layout, since the cell lays out its subviews as it prefers to have them.

If you want to use another layout, you'll have to make your own cell and use that. Quoting the documentation of `UITableViewCell`:

> If you want a table cell that has a
>   configuration different that those
>   defined by UITableViewCell for style,
>   you must create your own custom celle

Comment: He didn't mention wanting a different cell-style though. The cell-style layout changes nicely if you put in a smaller or larger cell.imageview.image. He simply needs to make his image smaller.

Comment: Well, he said he wanted to change the imageView frame, and this doesn't work in standard cells as they layout their subviews themselves. You are right though that the cell adapts to different image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize it to show high resolution images on retina display, you can also save a second image with double resolution and name it with @2x postfix.