# How can I crop images in cell.imageview.image for UITableViews?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimageview

I've read about this [here](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-rounded-corners-on-uitableviewcell-image-view/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812305/how-to-set-the-cell-imageview-frame) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553331/resize-cell-uiimageview-image) - but haven't been able to figure it out.
I have a UITableView that displays an image thumbnail (with the width of 66px), but when it's displayed in the table the images don't line up nicely which throws the text off and makes things look unpolished:

[image: UITableView with images out of alignment]

Here's my attempt to limit it to these dimensions in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIImage *largeImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 49); 

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
```

But it seems to make no difference. 
I don't mind cropping the thumbnail file when I add it if that is the easiest way, but it needs to work on iPhone and iPad.

What's the simplest solution?

CellForRow Method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

 //Configure the cell...
Story *storyAtCell = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//this should be the sentence object in sentences with an order of 0
NSPredicate *predicateTitle = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order=0"];
NSSet *sentences = [[storyAtCell sentences] filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicateTitle];
Sentence *sentenceAtCell = [sentences anyObject];

cell.textLabel.text = sentenceAtCell.text;

NSArray *paths       = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *uniquePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sentenceAtCell thumb]];


// This should crop it as you want - you've just got to create cropRect.

UIImage *largeImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];


//CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 66, 50); 
//CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([largeImage CGImage], cropRect);

//Discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643818/how-can-i-crop-images-in-cell-imageview-image-for-uitableviews

UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 66, 50)];
UILabel *labelFrame = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 70, 50)];

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellimage];
[cell.contentView addSubview:labelFrame];
[cellimage setImage:largeImage];


//cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cellimage];
//CGImageRelease(imageRef);
[cellimage release];
[labelFrame release];

cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: check my last comment in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the ImageView size works great for me :

```
UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 107, 70)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellimage];
    [cellimage setImageWithURL:[self.Featured_ImageURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1]    
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small_news_default.png"] View:@"Highlights"]; // you have to change this based on your code.
    [cellimage release];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that makes the images the perfect size, but they are now overlapping / clipping my cell text - how do you fix that?

Comment: make a Uilabel with frame more than 107 ..(width of image view) and add that too to the contentView.

Comment: UILabel *labelFrame = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 70, 50)]; just swaps out the image for a whitebox and doesn't move the text. (My imageview width is 66px).

Comment: UIImageView *cellimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 66, 50)];
    UILabel *labelFrame = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , 70, 50)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellimage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:labelFrame];
    [cellimage setImage:largeImage];

    
    [cellimage release];
    [labelFrame release];

Comment: label should be declared like this ...  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0 , 140, 50)];  you have to set its origin more than the image width

Comment: That last label declaration makes: [image] [white space] [clipped text] in each row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8882/discussion-between-shubhank-and-glenstorey)